# Webhost has ports blocked need to check status of game server

Tags: php, server, port, status, blocked

hi i am totally new to php / coding

I have a game server running on my pc, and the website php files of the gameserve is on a free hosting servive, and connects to my local pc SQL dbase.

i am unable to check online status of my game server thru website as the host blocks ports 2106 and 7777

'Login: 
Game: '

what are my options in checking the status if the host wont open the ports ?

Comment: Run a local webserver on your gameserver that checks the status and retrieve the output on your remote host on plain port 80 (the web).

Comment: As i said i am totally new hope you really dont mind me asking nub questions.. i already have the game website running on local and its checking the online status perfectly, now i am wondering how i retrieve this information from the local website to the hosted one.

Comment: I'm simply answering your question. You install a local webserver, something like [wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or [xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html). There you write a PHP script that checks if the ports are open or not and echo's that information out. Next you write a PHP script on your hosting service that retrieves that output and displays it on the web.

Comment: yup i have wamp running on my pc and a php script written to check the status of the game servers. is there a possibility to get a sample which i can look into, for the hosting side ( retrieve the out put ) .

Comment: `<?php $url = "http://0.0.0.0/path/to/php/file/that/outputs/it.php"; $output = file_get_contents($url); echo $url; ?>` Where 0.0.0.0 is of course the ip adres of your local server.

Comment: thank you very much icecub appreciate your help

Comment: No problem. Hope it'll work out for you. Let me know if you still require help at a later point.